# Can Appium run some test on several real Android devices connected by wifi

Tags: android, appium, adb, android-sdk-manager

I've read this tutorial:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/tutorial-how-to-run-tests-on-real-android-device-remotely-through-wi-fi/1135

to connect adb to a smartphone through wifi.

If you want to run some adb command when you have several smartphones connected, you need to specify the ip of the device:

```
adb -s 199.64.70.96:3389 *some command*
```

I think Appium is running some adb command based on the bid of smartphone, not the ip.

So I am pretty sure Appium cannot work with real smartphones connected by wifi.

Can you confirm my thought?
Or is it possible, and if yes, should I do something special with Appium to make it work with wifi connected devices?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way of doing it - https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android, hopfully it will do the job